# RabbitMQ : binding from a DLX

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

I've searched for that information (including the [docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)) and I can't find it.

I'm using the latest version of [php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) with RabbitMQ v. 2.7.1. I have three queues and three exchanges :

```
// Declare the exchanges
$this->channel->exchange_declare(self::EXCHANGE_TO_PROCESS, 'direct', false, true, false, false, false);
$this->channel->exchange_declare(self::EXCHANGE_WAITING, 'direct', false, true, false, false, false);
$this->channel->exchange_declare(self::EXCHANGE_TO_CLEAN, 'direct', false, true, false, false, false);

// Messages in the to_process queue are sent to to_clean after 24 hours without being processed
$this->channel->queue_declare(self::QUEUE_TO_PROCESS, false, true, false, false, false, array(
    'x-dead-letter-exchange' => array('S', self::EXCHANGE_TO_CLEAN),
    'x-message-ttl' => array('I', 86400000), // 1 day in milli-seconds
));

// Messages in the waiting queue are sent to to_process after 5 minutes (wait period before retry)
$this->channel->queue_declare(self::QUEUE_WAITING, false, true, false, false, false, array(
    'x-dead-letter-exchange' => array('S', self::EXCHANGE_TO_PROCESS),
    'x-message-ttl' => array('I', 300000), // 5 minutes in milli-seconds
));

// Messages in the to_clean queue are kept until they are processed
$this->channel->queue_declare(self::QUEUE_TO_CLEAN, false, true, false, false, false);

// Bind the queues to the exchanges
$this->channel->queue_bind(self::QUEUE_TO_PROCESS, self::EXCHANGE_TO_PROCESS);
$this->channel->queue_bind(self::QUEUE_TO_CLEAN, self::EXCHANGE_TO_CLEAN);
$this->channel->queue_bind(self::QUEUE_WAITING, self::EXCHANGE_WAITING);
```

The behavior is pretty straightforward : messages are published into the `EXCHANGE_TO_PROCESS`. An external worker processes the message : if the processing goes A-OK, the message is simply ACK'ed and thus removed from the queue (this part works perfectly) ; if the processing goes wrong, the message is instead inserted into the `EXCHANGE_WAITING` where, after a TTL of 5 minutes, it is reinserted through DLX into the `EXCHANGE_TO_PROCESS` for re-processing. After the third failure, though, it is inserted into the `EXCHANGE_TO_CLEAN` where a cron job will come and clean up messages, log errors, etc.

The problem I've run into, however, is that the code clearly binds the `QUEUE_WAITING` to the `EXCHANGE_WAITING` (as expected), but when I look into the RabbitMQ management page, I notice that **two** queues are bound to that exchange, namely `QUEUE_TO_PROCESS` and `QUEUE_WAITING`, in that order. When the 5 minutes are over, the message then disappears. I'm not quite sure why.

All this to bring us to my questions : does the dead letter exchange implicitly bind the exchange in parameter to the queue? And : what could possibly be happening to my lost messages?

**EDIT**

I'm even more confused than I was. I've tried the following, very basic code :

```
    $this->channel->exchange_declare('exchangeA', 'fanout', false, true, false, false, false);
    $this->channel->exchange_declare('exchangeB', 'fanout', false, true, false, false, false);
    $this->channel->queue_declare('queueA', false, true, false, false, false, array(
        'x-dead-letter-exchange' => array('S', 'exchangeB'),
        'x-message-ttl' => array('I', 5000)
    ));
    $this->channel->queue_declare('queueB', false, true, false, false, false);
    $this->channel->queue_bind('queueA', 'exchangeA');
    $this->channel->queue_bind('queueB', 'exchangeB');

    $msg = new AMQPMessage('hello!');
    $this->channel->basic_publish($msg, 'exchangeA');
```

This creates two queues and two exchanges (I've seen them to `fanout` to avoid bothering with routing keys), binds queueA to exchangeA and queueB to exchangeB, setting a TTL on queueA and its DLX to exchangeB. Watching what happens in the management page, I see a message spending 5 seconds in queueA, as expected, and then the message disappears, just like in my more complex code above.

Comment: Please clarify what php library (or extension) are you using.

Comment: Indeed, that wasn't specified : I'm using the latest version of php-amqplib. I added the right tag and I'll update the text of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got doubts that something was amiss when I stumbled upon [this blog](http://yuserinterface.com/dev/2013/01/08/how-to-schedule-delay-messages-with-rabbitmq-using-a-dead-letter-exchange/) and saw the poster with a case very similar to ours and he mentioned it was working without problems... so I started digging a bit more.

The problem we had was simply a version problem. I'd been told the RabbitMQ package was up to date but we're using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS so the "up to date" version was 2.7.1 - a version that's over 3 years old.

If you're in the same case as we were (using an older distro), checkout RabbitMQ's [download page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html) and pick the one that fits your distro. In the case of [Ubuntu](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html), we simply added the official repo (you can also simply download the .dpkg file), performed an `apt-get update` and waited for the server to reboot. Afterwards, the above code worked pretty much as is.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your message flow may get cycled. If so, RabbitMQ will silently drop message as it specified in official docs ([Routing Dead-Lettered Messages](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) section):

> It is possible to form a cycle of dead-letter queues. For instance,
>   this can happen when a queue dead-letters messages to the default
>   exchange without specifiying a dead-letter routing key. Messages in
>   such cycles (i.e. messages that reach the same queue twice) will be
>   dropped if the entire cycle is due to message expiry.

To deal with cycling problem you have to pick one choice:

1. Break the cycle at all (drop message at some point).
2. **Or** consume messages from stalled queue and re-publish them manually according to your workflow.

This brings some complexity to your application but it is the price you have to pay for performance and stability.

P.S.:

I dig RabbitMQ mailing list and found similar question like your - [Dead Letter, TTL and Cycle](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-April/026487.html):

> At the moment you would have to consume and republish to purge the 
>   header outside of RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, that seems like my problem. Do you have any suggestion about how I should handle this problem? I could, for instance, create two more queues (say, failure1 and failure2) where messages that failed processing would go to, but that seems a bit inelegant and overkill but if you have a better solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: Consume messages from `self::QUEUE_WAITING` manually and then publish them to `self::EXCHANGE_TO_PROCESS` "as-is" (with the same routing key). In fact I would also suggest you to use only one exchange for your task but utilize `x-dead-letter-routing-key` power (unless you have some reason to do like you did). But your workflow is also ok, but having less entities is looks a bit cleaner for me. Also updated my answer with solution to deal with rabbitmq cycling protection.